# Script galera new cluster error occured when bootstrapping

Tags: chef-infra, mariadb, centos7, galera

I am trying to bootstrap a node with galera_new_cluster script and I've got this error :

```
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of       galera_new_cluster &&       touch /etc/my.cnf.d/cluster_bootstraped
 ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: /usr/bin/galera_new_cluster: line 31: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
---- End output of       galera_new_cluster &&       touch /etc/my.cnf.d/cluster_bootstraped
 ----
Ran       galera_new_cluster &&       touch /etc/my.cnf.d/cluster_bootstraped
 returned 1
```

Line31 refers to return cmd into the script.

My configuration :

```
+wsrep_on = ON
+wsrep_provider = /usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
+binlog_format = row
+default_storage_engine = InnoDB
+innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2
+bind-address = 0.0.0.0
+wsrep_cluster_name = MariaDB_Cluster
+wsrep_sst_method = mariabackup
+wsrep_sst_auth = root:password
+wsrep_cluster_address = gcomm://mdb01,mdb02,mdb03
+wsrep_node_address = mdb03
```

I am working with mariadb 10.3, CHEF 13 and Centos 7.

thank you.

Comment: Could you please show your script? It seems it is something not correct there.

Comment: seems like the version 10.3.10 of mariadb has an error into galera_new_cluster.sh 
line 31 refers to statement 'return $var' instead of 'exit $var'.  A Jira ticket has been opened due to this issue. 
[https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17379]